# How to access hidden dropdown menu using Java Selenium webdriver

Tags: javascript, java, selenium, drop-down-menu, selenium-webdriver

I want to access a hidden dropdown menu on a webpage using selenium webdriver.
First I have to click an option from a navigation bar, after clicking on that option the dropdown menu appears and then I want to select a value from the menu list.

Can anyone tell me how can this be done using Java selenium webdriver.
The html tags do not have a unique name and id. They have class name which dynamically changes after clicking the options in navigation bar.

Comment: Without showing the HTML structure of the page (or sharing a link) and the attempts you've made, this is going to be "too broad". Please improve your question.

Comment: Following is the HTML snapshot:

<div id="navbar" class="navbar-collapse collapse secondnav" aria-expanded="false">
            <ul class="demo">
            <li>
            <li class="test">
                      <a class="test-toggle" aria-expanded="false"              role="button" data-toggle="test" href="#"> Reports
                      <span class="caret"></span>
                      </a>
            <ul class="test-menu" role="menu">
        <li></li>
        <li></li>
        <li></li>
        <li></li>
<li></li>
<li></li>

Answer (score 0):

Since you are just testing it, feed static choices to it.

Using the Selenium WebDriver find the div for an item in the navigation bar (choose any one if its trivial or choose the one specific to the test case). If the navbar doesn't have unique name or id, maybe by xpath or css path which will require making a variable and than referencing it in your test.